# I can't edit the Date & Time picker in React Material UI on Laptop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It is working well on other platforms except for the Laptop.
I've been starting to use material-ui was looking into using DatePicker and TimePicker. I don't know if it's a bug or that i did something wrong, but after searching everywhere i'm not able to make those 2 components works. They simply don't show, nothing happens when i click on them and when i tab itdoesn't focus them.

```
<TextField
        id="datetime-local"
        label="Start time"
        type="datetime-local"
        variant="outlined"
        defaultValue={new Date().toISOString()}
        className={classes.textField}
        InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
        }}
        style={{width:'100%'}}
        onChange={(event)=>{
            const day = new Date(event.target.value);
            setSelectedDate(day);
        }}
    />
```

Comment: Please add your code in codesandbox and share so that we can help you

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-drake-g93z5

I have uploaded that code.

Comment: Its is working perfectly fine if you click on the calendar icon in the right it will show you picker from where you can select date and time. Please let me know if thats not what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks.
But I said before, it was working well except with the Laptop platform.
So I wanted to fix that issue.
Please check on Laptop enviroment.

Comment: Yes Happy, I am using it in my mac book and it is working fine it can be more of a browser issue which browser and what version are you using?